# nodejs: display an image not in public folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I would like to display an image which is not in the public folder in my webroot.
My hirarchy:

```
Webroot
--core
----views
----public <- Here is where stylesheets and other images are
------index.ejs <- Here I want to display the file.jpg
--data
----userdata
------username <- this folder is named by the user
--------assignment <- this folder is named by the assignment
----------file.jpg
```

I have no idea, i could move this into the public folder and rule it by the robots.txt, but I thought, maybe there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serve the `data` directory as a static directory, like your public directory -- [Serving static files in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). You'll probably want to set up some authentication middleware before the static route or everyone will be able to see each others data.

Here's an example of what that might look like:

```
// User authentication middleware
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // Some implementation that determines the user that made the request.
    req.username = 'foo';
    next();
});

// Serve the public assets to all authenticated users
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Prevent users from accessing other users data
app.use('/data/userdata/{username}/*', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.username === req.path.username) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(401); // Unauthorized
    }
});

// Serve the data assets to users that passed through the previous route
app.use('/data', express.static('data'));
```

Comment: I get the message: Cannot get /data/userdata/username/ Edit: Okay, If i specify a file, it works

Comment: Then add another `app.use` for that route.

Comment: Okay. It worked. Now i only have to make an authentication for PDF Files too :D Because this doesnt work. It opens the pdf file and in the console i get status 401. But i will try, thanks at all :D